Compute $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{x^3-2y^3}{x^2+|y|}$ with polar coordinates

Let's consider the following function:
$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}\frac{x^3-2y^3}{x^2+|y|}, & (x,y)\ne (0,0) \\ 0, & (x,y)=(0,0)\end{cases}$$
Establish whether $f(x,y)$ is continuous or not at the point $(x,y)=(0,0)$.

I have to verify that $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{x^3-2y^3}{x^2+|y|}=0$.
First, I look for a candidate limit value.
If I consider the restriction $f(x,0)=x$, then $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} f(x,0)=0$. Therefore, if the limits exists, it has to be equal to zero.
To prove the claim, I change cartesian coordinates into polar coordinates as follows:
$$\begin{cases}x=\rho \cos(\theta) \\ y=\rho\sin(\theta)\end{cases}$$ where $\rho>0$ and $\theta\in [0,2\pi]$.
Now, I have that:
$$0\leq\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\left|\frac{x^3-2y^3}{x^2+|y|}\right|= \lim_{\rho \to 0}\sup_{\theta\in [0,2\pi]}\left|\frac{\rho^3\cos^3(\theta)-2\rho^3\sin^3(\theta)}{\rho^2\cos^2(\theta)+\rho|\sin(\theta)|}\right|\leq $$ $$\leq\lim_{\rho \to 0}\sup_{\theta\in [0,2\pi]}\frac{\rho^3\left(|\cos^3(\theta)|+2|\sin^3(\theta)|\right)}{\rho\left(\rho\cos^2(\theta)+|\sin(\theta)|\right)}=$$
$$=\lim_{\rho \to 0}\sup_{\theta\in [0,2\pi]}\frac{\rho^2\left(|\cos^3(\theta)|+2|\sin^3(\theta)|\right)}{\rho\cos^2(\theta)+|\sin(\theta)|}\leq \lim_{\rho\to 0}\sup_{\theta\in [0,2\pi]}\frac{3\rho^2}{\rho\cos^2(\theta)+|\sin(\theta)|}=(\clubsuit)$$
The expression $\rho\cos^2(\theta)+|\sin(\theta)|$ is non zero for all $\theta\in [0,2\pi]$ and it is minimized for $\theta=0$. So, the expression $$\frac{1}{\rho\cos^2(\theta)+|\sin(\theta)|}$$ is maximized for $\theta=0$.
Therefore, $$(\clubsuit)\leq \lim_{\rho \to 0}\frac{3\rho^2}{\rho}=\lim_{\rho\to 0}3\rho=0.$$
In definitive, I get that:
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{x^3-2y^3}{x^2+|y|}=0$$ and so $f(x,y)$ is continuous at $(0,0)$.
Is my procedure correct? Is there another way to do it?

Applying the triangle inequality is probably faster

Do you mean $$0\leq \left|\frac{x^3-2y^3}{x^2+|y|}\right|\leq \frac{|x^3|+2|y^3|}{x^2+|y|}= \frac{|x^3|}{x^2+|y|}+\frac{2|y^3|}{x^2+|y|}\leq |x|+y^2\to 0?$$

Easier yet, $y^2\le |y|$ for $|y|\le 1$, so $x^2+|y|\ge x^2+y^2$.

Oh great, thanks! Anyway, is what I did above and in my post still correct?

It seems ok, but I would like to discourage you from abusing polar coordinates. You can find hundreds of posts on this site with flawed arguments in polar coordinates.

HINT
You can also proceed like this:
\begin{align*}
\frac{x^{3} - 2y^{3}}{x^{2} + |y|} & = x\left(\frac{x^{2}}{x^{2} + |y|}\right) - 2y^{2}\left(\frac{y}{x^{2} + |y|}\right)
\end{align*}
Then apply the squeeze theorem to each term separately.
Can you take it from here?

Is the following correct? $$0\leq \left|\frac{x^3-2y^3}{x^2+|y|}\right|\leq \frac{|x^3|+2|y^3|}{x^2+|y|}= \frac{|x^3|}{x^2+|y|}+\frac{2|y^3|}{x^2+|y|}\leq |x|+y^2\to 0$$

Almost. The last inequality should be $\ldots\leq |x| + 2y^{2}$.
